# Geb test: misses form element

Tags: jquery, grails, gsp, geb

I have Geb test in my Grails app that completely misses the form element.  I watch the test run and the element itself doesn't fill or run at all.  What could I be doing wrong?

Form element GSP:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label id="business" class="col-sm-2 control-label topsidelabel" for="business">Business</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label id="business-label" class="toplabel" for="business">Name</label>
        <g:textField id="business" name="business" maxlength="50" class="form-control" value="${....business}" aria-labelledby="business-label"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Geb test selector (2 different attempts):

```
$('#business').value('5150 Studios')
$("form").business == "5150 Studios"
```

Form HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label id="business" class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="">Business</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label id="Name-label" class="toplabel" for="Name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="business" maxlength="50" class="form-control" value="" id="business" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i see 2 id="business"

Comment: Can you post the HTML produced by the gsp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two elements with the ID `business`. When you call `$('#business')` geb will return a list of Navigator objects which match the given selector. In this case you are receiving two Navigators back as you have two elements which match the selector. To solve your problem, either rename one of the two `business` elements or call:

```
$('#business')[1].value('5150 Studios')
```

Comment: do the <label id="business"> and the <g:textField id="business"> constitute the two instances?  I didn't know those could qualify as two separate instances of the same thing?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking. If you post the HTML produced by your GSP file then everything should be a lot clearer.

Comment: how do I find that html?  If I go in Firefox -> Tools -> Web Developer -> View Source...  all I get is the html that I already posted.

Comment: The HTML you see in Firefox won't have the grails <g:> tags

Comment: added it to the original post

Comment: As you can see from the HTML you've posted, you do indeed have 2 elements with the same ID (business). My answer should fix your problem. I recommend just changing the <label>'s id to "business_label" or something appropriate like that, and geb should be able to work with it.

Comment: is it the conflict between the label Id and the field id?  Because I think I've tried it removing the field Id and Geb still misses it.

Comment: I'd imagine so, yes. Your `<input>` tag has the id `business`, and so does your first `<label>` tag. If you've changed it to ensure that there are no conflicting IDs, could you add a println and show what geb is returning when you do `println $('#business')`